# DevExpress MVC GridView issues when using TokenBox columns and BindToEF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I am using GridView from an old version 14.2.6 of DevExpress MVC (and have no option update it).

Recently because of performance issue I changed the model from IEnumerable to IQueryable and .Bind to .BindToEF. Because of that it speed up drastically.
However, I noticed that some functionalities stoped working for columns with type **TokenBox** (*Source* column in my example).
Columns of other types (ComboBox, DateEdit, ...) works as expected.

When I click on the "pin" to display filter items in the header the list is empty however, there are items in this columns:

[image]

When I click on this column header to sort all displayed data becomes empty:

[image]

When I get back to IEnumerable model (instead of IQueryable) and .Bind (insted o .BindToEF) everything works as expected.

Parts of the code:

```
@model IQueryable<SupplierPricingItem>
@*@model IEnumerable<SupplierPricingItem>*@

_grid.BindToEF(string.Empty, string.Empty, (s, e) =>
{
    e.QueryableSource = Model;
    e.KeyExpression = "Id";
}).GetHtml();
// _grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml();

settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = nameof(SupplierPricingItem.SourceLanguagesIdsString);
    column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.TokenBox;
    var tbProperties = column.PropertiesEdit as TokenBoxProperties;
    tbProperties.DataSource = ViewBag.AllSourceLanguages;
    tbProperties.TextField = "Name";
    tbProperties.ValueField = "Id";
    column.Settings.AllowAutoFilter = DefaultBoolean.False;
});
```